# Error: Bad username/password nodemailer-sengrid-transport use NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid, nodemailer

I try to build activate email but I had a problem.

```
 var email = {
                    from: 'Localhost staff, staff@locahost.com',
                    to: user.email,
                    subject: 'Localhsot activation link',
                    text: 'Hello ' + user.name + ', Thank you for regstring at localhost.com. Please click in the following link to compelet your activation: http://localhost:8000/activate/' + user.tomporarytoken,
                    html: 'Hello<strong>' + user.name + '</strong>,<br><br> Thank you for regstring at localhost.com. Please click in the link below to compelet your activation: <br><br><a href="http://localhost:8000/activate/' + user.tomporarytoken + '" >http://localhost:8000/activate/</a> ' 
                    };

                client.sendMail(email, function(err, info){
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                }
                });
                res.json({ success: true, message: 'Account registed!, Please check your e-mail for activation link.' });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When completing the registration he should have reached the last case and give me a message set but give me an error, what happen ?

```
Error: Bad username / password
at Request._callback (C:\Users\Hi.Tech\Documents\Mohammed ELamine\Index\Project Simple (Backend + frontend)\Full-Stack-Mean-Js\node_modules\sendgrid\lib\sendgrid.js:88:25)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Hi.Tech\Documents\Mohammed ELamine\Index\Project Simple (Backend + frontend)\Full-Stack-Mean-Js\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hi.Tech\Documents\Mohammed ELamine\Index\Project Simple (Backend + frontend)\Full-Stack-Mean-Js\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hi.Tech\Documents\Mohammed ELamine\Index\Project Simple (Backend + frontend)\Full-Stack-Mean-Js\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should implement node mailer. There are fields which you should fill, you didn't. Try this way and you can send email.

```
const messageStructure = {
         from: 'EMAIL',
         to: targetAddress,
         subject,
         attachments,
         html: emailBody
      };
      const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
         host: 'EMAIL_HOST',
         port: PORT,
         secure: false/true,
         auth: {
            user: 'FROM_EMAIL',
            pass: 'FROM_EMAIL_PASSWORD'
         }
      });
      transporter.sendMail(messageStructure, (err, info) => {
         if (err) {
            reject(err);
            printer.printError(err);
         } else {
            printer.printHighlightedLog(info);
            resolve(false);
         }
      });
```

Comment: what is email host here?, is the sendgrid email id itself?